# How to use having() in tableGateway in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

How to use having() clause in ZF2?

There is almost no examples on the web how to prepare correct select object with having.

I have query like:

```
SELECT root_schema_id as `schema_id`
FROM `standard_specific_root_schemas`
WHERE `vehicle_id` IN (".implode(",",$vehiclesIds).")
GROUP BY `schema_id`, rootSubGroup_id HAVING count(*)=".$noOfVehicles
```

And I'm trying to run it in ZF2:

```
public function getVehicleWithinCommonRootSubgroupInSpecific($vehiclesIds)
{
    $where = new Where();
    $where->in('vehicle_id', $vehiclesIds);

    $having = new Having('count(*) = '.count($vehiclesIds));

    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function (Select $select) use ($where, $having) {
        $select
            ->where($where)
            ->having($having);
    });

    if (!$rowset) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find schemas for group $groupId");
    }
    return $rowset;
}
```

Of course that part in ZF2 is not finished yet as I wanted to check if it's working first.
I've tried few ways of providing params to having method but everything generates errors.

Help please, I'm desperate...

Comment: Need to add `->columns(array('schema_id' => 'root_schema_id'))` to `$select` to choose correct columns for grouping. (see the comments below answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I cannot test your query, but can try and reproduce the query you need.

I adjusted the having to use ->expression() instead of a variable via the construct.
I also added the group statement.

To view the query I added a var_dump:

```
    $where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
    $where->in('vehicle_id', $vehiclesIds);

    $having = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Having();
    $having->expression('count(*) = ?', count($vehiclesIds));

    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(function (\Zend\Db\Sql\Select $select) use ($where, $having) {
        $select
            ->where($where)
            ->group(array('schema_id', 'rootSubGroup_id'))
            ->having($having);

        var_dump( $select->getSqlString() );
    });
```

Let me know if this helps.

---

To circumvent the error mentioned in the comments you would have to do something like below:

```
$sql = $this->tableGateway->getSql();

$select = $sql->select();

$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();
$where->in('vehicle_id', $vehiclesIds);

$having = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Having();
$having->expression('count(*) = ?', count($vehiclesIds));

$select
    ->where($where)
    ->group(array('schema_id', 'rootSubGroup_id'))
    ->having($having);

$preparedQuery = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);

var_dump( $preparedQuery->getSql() );
```

However, if I'm right, the tableGateway does this for you so the error should go away once you start using the select to query the database.

Also, you can use the above to do that too, just replace this:

```
$preparedQuery = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);

var_dump( $preparedQuery->getSql() );
```

With:

```
$this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
```

Comment: Thanks it's working correctly. It seems like I had something similat while ago but I've ignored it as I'm getting following error: `Attempting to quote a value without specific driver level support can introduce security vulnerabilities in a production environment. in \vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\Sql92.php on line 80`. Anyway generated SQL is OK. Thanks

Comment: Yes you would get that this way. Using a `$sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);` should get rid of that. And you're very welcome, thanks for replying!

Comment: Is it any way to use it here? How to get $sql object here?

Comment: You don't need it for the actual result, however, I've updated my answer with a way to do it.

Comment: Perfect for me! Thanks! I've also added `->columns(array('schema_id' => 'root_schema_id'))` to make SQL it exactly the same and allow grouping to work correctly.